# TYPO3 how to hide List-Records

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

We have a folder with records, for example to display event-records in the typo3 backend. now we need to hide some of those events in the backend list-module based on a value (true/false) of one column. i cant find a solution within the TCA-documentation. any ideas how to achieve that?

help is much appreciated

Comment: If you set deleted=1 on the records they are hidden in BE. Why are this records needed but now showed in backend?

Comment: onDatabaseOperation we Save recurring events - these should be hidden as changes in the „Patent“ Event also modify all recurring events

Comment: i mean "Parent" not "Patent"

Answer (score 0):

our solution is to change the pid of the records which should be hidden so they appear in a subdirectory where the access is set to exclude our customer.